# Python: Find the structure of a molecule using previously known bonds

Tags: python-3.x

I have data that represents atoms in a molecule. In first row and first column I have the atoms in the molecule and the rest of the list contains either distance between pairs of atoms or `'BOND'` which means that these atoms are bound to each other. Every element on the diagonal is `0` because `ls[0][index]` is the same atom as `ls[index][0]` so the distance between this pair of atoms is `0`.

```
ls = [['', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'N'],
['C', 0.0, 'BOND', 2.525, 3.892, 5.08, 6.414, 7.632, 'BOND', 2.124, 2.141, 2.77, 2.732, 4.163, 4.19, 5.208, 5.189, 6.582, 6.598, 8.551, 7.758, 7.745, 1.892, 'BOND'],
['C', 'BOND', 0.0, 'BOND', 2.557, 3.928, 5.115, 6.444, 2.205, 'BOND', 'BOND', 2.16, 2.162, 2.78, 2.778, 4.212, 4.214, 5.229, 5.228, 7.288, 6.66, 6.661, 2.577, 2.499],
['C', 2.525, 'BOND', 0.0, 'BOND', 2.555, 3.926, 5.107, 2.842, 2.157, 2.174, 'BOND', 'BOND', 2.156, 2.156, 2.78, 2.781, 4.209, 4.208, 6.036, 5.263, 5.264, 3.705, 3.559],
['C', 3.892, 2.557, 'BOND', 0.0, 'BOND', 2.558, 3.923, 4.259, 2.769, 2.81, 2.159, 2.157, 'BOND', 'BOND', 2.157, 2.157, 2.781, 2.782, 4.733, 4.243, 4.243, 4.854, 4.897],
['C', 5.08, 3.928, 2.555, 'BOND', 0.0, 'BOND', 2.552, 5.284, 4.2, 4.234, 2.785, 2.784, 2.157, 2.157, 'BOND', 'BOND', 2.155, 2.155, 3.503, 2.816, 2.817, 6.095, 6.078],
['C', 6.414, 5.115, 3.926, 2.558, 'BOND', 0.0, 'BOND', 6.674, 5.218, 5.26, 4.214, 4.213, 2.786, 2.784, 2.156, 2.156, 'BOND', 'BOND', 2.181, 2.176, 2.176, 7.318, 7.404],
['C', 7.632, 6.444, 5.107, 3.923, 2.552, 'BOND', 0.0, 7.794, 6.609, 6.647, 5.226, 5.225, 4.211, 4.21, 2.775, 2.774, 2.159, 2.159, 'BOND', 'BOND', 'BOND', 8.579, 8.614],
['H', 'BOND', 2.205, 2.842, 4.259, 5.284, 6.674, 7.794, 0.0, 2.534, 3.093, 3.174, 2.602, 4.428, 4.789, 5.471, 5.161, 6.784, 7.023, 8.751, 7.965, 7.754, 2.873, 2.011],
['H', 2.124, 'BOND', 2.157, 2.769, 4.2, 5.218, 6.609, 2.534, 0.0, 1.764, 3.059, 2.51, 2.54, 3.082, 4.728, 4.395, 5.099, 5.39, 7.377, 6.993, 6.77, 3.319, 3.175],
['H', 2.141, 'BOND', 2.174, 2.81, 4.234, 5.26, 6.647, 3.093, 1.764, 0.0, 2.512, 3.072, 3.132, 2.584, 4.419, 4.761, 5.437, 5.141, 7.418, 6.802, 7.03, 2.303, 2.666],
['H', 2.77, 2.16, 'BOND', 2.159, 2.785, 4.214, 5.226, 3.174, 3.059, 2.512, 0.0, 1.753, 3.061, 2.512, 2.559, 3.102, 4.739, 4.403, 6.204, 5.152, 5.444, 3.591, 3.52],
['H', 2.732, 2.162, 'BOND', 2.157, 2.784, 4.213, 5.225, 2.602, 2.51, 3.072, 1.753, 0.0, 2.506, 3.06, 3.102, 2.56, 4.401, 4.737, 6.203, 5.444, 5.152, 4.29, 3.889],
['H', 4.163, 2.78, 2.156, 'BOND', 2.157, 2.786, 4.211, 4.428, 2.54, 3.132, 3.061, 2.506, 0.0, 1.753, 3.061, 2.508, 2.559, 3.103, 4.892, 4.769, 4.431, 5.278, 5.266],
['H', 4.19, 2.778, 2.156, 'BOND', 2.157, 2.784, 4.21, 4.789, 3.082, 2.584, 2.512, 3.06, 1.753, 0.0, 2.51, 3.06, 3.099, 2.557, 4.89, 4.432, 4.767, 4.73, 5.001],
['H', 5.208, 4.212, 2.78, 2.157, 'BOND', 2.156, 2.775, 5.471, 4.728, 4.419, 2.559, 3.102, 3.061, 2.51, 0.0, 1.753, 3.058, 2.506, 3.779, 2.593, 3.134, 6.029, 6.057],
['H', 5.189, 4.214, 2.781, 2.157, 'BOND', 2.156, 2.774, 5.161, 4.395, 4.761, 3.102, 2.56, 2.508, 3.06, 1.753, 0.0, 2.507, 3.058, 3.778, 3.132, 2.593, 6.47, 6.279],
['H', 6.582, 5.229, 4.209, 2.781, 2.155, 'BOND', 2.159, 6.784, 5.099, 5.437, 4.739, 4.401, 2.559, 3.099, 3.058, 2.507, 0.0, 1.752, 2.503, 3.075, 2.522, 7.606, 7.652],
['H', 6.598, 5.228, 4.208, 2.782, 2.155, 'BOND', 2.159, 7.023, 5.39, 5.141, 4.403, 4.737, 3.103, 2.557, 2.506, 3.058, 1.752, 0.0, 2.502, 2.522, 3.075, 7.235, 7.472],
['H', 8.551, 7.288, 6.036, 4.733, 3.503, 2.181, 'BOND', 8.751, 7.377, 7.418, 6.204, 6.203, 4.892, 4.89, 3.779, 3.778, 2.503, 2.502, 0.0, 1.766, 1.766, 9.443, 9.532],
['H', 7.758, 6.66, 5.263, 4.243, 2.816, 2.176, 'BOND', 7.965, 6.993, 6.802, 5.152, 5.444, 4.769, 4.432, 2.593, 3.132, 3.075, 2.522, 1.766, 0.0, 1.764, 8.571, 8.641],
['H', 7.745, 6.661, 5.264, 4.243, 2.817, 2.176, 'BOND', 7.754, 6.77, 7.03, 5.444, 5.152, 4.431, 4.767, 3.134, 2.593, 2.522, 3.075, 1.766, 1.764, 0.0, 8.889, 8.799],
['H', 1.892, 2.577, 3.705, 4.854, 6.095, 7.318, 8.579, 2.873, 3.319, 2.303, 3.591, 4.29, 5.278, 4.73, 6.029, 6.47, 7.606, 7.235, 9.443, 8.571, 8.889, 0.0, 'BOND'],
['N', 'BOND', 2.499, 3.559, 4.897, 6.078, 7.404, 8.614, 2.011, 3.175, 2.666, 3.52, 3.889, 5.266, 5.001, 6.057, 6.279, 7.652, 7.472, 9.532, 8.641, 8.799, 'BOND', 0.0]]
```

What I want to do is to find how many bonds away each atom is from an atom defined as "start". I always define nitrogen or oxygen as "start" (this molecule doesn't contain oxygen). So for example if I have a carbon that is bound to nitrogen ("start"), it is 1 carbon bond away from start. If another carbon is bound to this carbon, it is 2 carbon bond away from the start. Third carbon which is bound to this carbon, is 3 carbon bonds away from start etc.

My approach to this problem is as follows:

1. Find "start" atom and its index
2. Find all atoms that have "BOND" to "start" atom, these are 1 bond away from "start"
3. Find all atoms that have "BOND" to the atoms that are 1 bond away except the ones that I checked in previous loop. These atoms are 2 bonds away from "start"
4. Find all atoms that have "BOND" to atoms that are 2 bonds away, except the ones that I checked in previous loop. These are 3 bonds away from "start", etc...
5. Continue this so long that all atoms are assigned with a distance from "start"

I want the output to be the same list that I loop through but so that I append the distance from "start" to the end of each row of the array. So the output should look like this:

```
output = [['', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'N'],
['C', 0.0, 'BOND', 2.525, 3.892, 5.08, 6.414, 7.632, 'BOND', 2.124, 2.141, 2.77, 2.732, 4.163, 4.19, 5.208, 5.189, 6.582, 6.598, 8.551, 7.758, 7.745, 1.892, 'BOND', num],
['C', 'BOND', 0.0, 'BOND', 2.557, 3.928, 5.115, 6.444, 2.205, 'BOND', 'BOND', 2.16, 2.162, 2.78, 2.778, 4.212, 4.214, 5.229, 5.228, 7.288, 6.66, 6.661, 2.577, 2.499, num],
['C', 2.525, 'BOND', 0.0, 'BOND', 2.555, 3.926, 5.107, 2.842, 2.157, 2.174, 'BOND', 'BOND', 2.156, 2.156, 2.78, 2.781, 4.209, 4.208, 6.036, 5.263, 5.264, 3.705, 3.559, num],
['C', 3.892, 2.557, 'BOND', 0.0, 'BOND', 2.558, 3.923, 4.259, 2.769, 2.81, 2.159, 2.157, 'BOND', 'BOND', 2.157, 2.157, 2.781, 2.782, 4.733, 4.243, 4.243, 4.854, 4.897, num],
['C', 5.08, 3.928, 2.555, 'BOND', 0.0, 'BOND', 2.552, 5.284, 4.2, 4.234, 2.785, 2.784, 2.157, 2.157, 'BOND', 'BOND', 2.155, 2.155, 3.503, 2.816, 2.817, 6.095, 6.078, num],
['C', 6.414, 5.115, 3.926, 2.558, 'BOND', 0.0, 'BOND', 6.674, 5.218, 5.26, 4.214, 4.213, 2.786, 2.784, 2.156, 2.156, 'BOND', 'BOND', 2.181, 2.176, 2.176, 7.318, 7.404, num],
['C', 7.632, 6.444, 5.107, 3.923, 2.552, 'BOND', 0.0, 7.794, 6.609, 6.647, 5.226, 5.225, 4.211, 4.21, 2.775, 2.774, 2.159, 2.159, 'BOND', 'BOND', 'BOND', 8.579, 8.614, num],
['H', 'BOND', 2.205, 2.842, 4.259, 5.284, 6.674, 7.794, 0.0, 2.534, 3.093, 3.174, 2.602, 4.428, 4.789, 5.471, 5.161, 6.784, 7.023, 8.751, 7.965, 7.754, 2.873, 2.011, num],
['H', 2.124, 'BOND', 2.157, 2.769, 4.2, 5.218, 6.609, 2.534, 0.0, 1.764, 3.059, 2.51, 2.54, 3.082, 4.728, 4.395, 5.099, 5.39, 7.377, 6.993, 6.77, 3.319, 3.175, num],
['H', 2.141, 'BOND', 2.174, 2.81, 4.234, 5.26, 6.647, 3.093, 1.764, 0.0, 2.512, 3.072, 3.132, 2.584, 4.419, 4.761, 5.437, 5.141, 7.418, 6.802, 7.03, 2.303, 2.666, num],
['H', 2.77, 2.16, 'BOND', 2.159, 2.785, 4.214, 5.226, 3.174, 3.059, 2.512, 0.0, 1.753, 3.061, 2.512, 2.559, 3.102, 4.739, 4.403, 6.204, 5.152, 5.444, 3.591, 3.52, num],
['H', 2.732, 2.162, 'BOND', 2.157, 2.784, 4.213, 5.225, 2.602, 2.51, 3.072, 1.753, 0.0, 2.506, 3.06, 3.102, 2.56, 4.401, 4.737, 6.203, 5.444, 5.152, 4.29, 3.889, num],
['H', 4.163, 2.78, 2.156, 'BOND', 2.157, 2.786, 4.211, 4.428, 2.54, 3.132, 3.061, 2.506, 0.0, 1.753, 3.061, 2.508, 2.559, 3.103, 4.892, 4.769, 4.431, 5.278, 5.266, num],
['H', 4.19, 2.778, 2.156, 'BOND', 2.157, 2.784, 4.21, 4.789, 3.082, 2.584, 2.512, 3.06, 1.753, 0.0, 2.51, 3.06, 3.099, 2.557, 4.89, 4.432, 4.767, 4.73, 5.001, num],
['H', 5.208, 4.212, 2.78, 2.157, 'BOND', 2.156, 2.775, 5.471, 4.728, 4.419, 2.559, 3.102, 3.061, 2.51, 0.0, 1.753, 3.058, 2.506, 3.779, 2.593, 3.134, 6.029, 6.057, num],
['H', 5.189, 4.214, 2.781, 2.157, 'BOND', 2.156, 2.774, 5.161, 4.395, 4.761, 3.102, 2.56, 2.508, 3.06, 1.753, 0.0, 2.507, 3.058, 3.778, 3.132, 2.593, 6.47, 6.279, num],
['H', 6.582, 5.229, 4.209, 2.781, 2.155, 'BOND', 2.159, 6.784, 5.099, 5.437, 4.739, 4.401, 2.559, 3.099, 3.058, 2.507, 0.0, 1.752, 2.503, 3.075, 2.522, 7.606, 7.652, num],
['H', 6.598, 5.228, 4.208, 2.782, 2.155, 'BOND', 2.159, 7.023, 5.39, 5.141, 4.403, 4.737, 3.103, 2.557, 2.506, 3.058, 1.752, 0.0, 2.502, 2.522, 3.075, 7.235, 7.472, num],
['H', 8.551, 7.288, 6.036, 4.733, 3.503, 2.181, 'BOND', 8.751, 7.377, 7.418, 6.204, 6.203, 4.892, 4.89, 3.779, 3.778, 2.503, 2.502, 0.0, 1.766, 1.766, 9.443, 9.532, num],
['H', 7.758, 6.66, 5.263, 4.243, 2.816, 2.176, 'BOND', 7.965, 6.993, 6.802, 5.152, 5.444, 4.769, 4.432, 2.593, 3.132, 3.075, 2.522, 1.766, 0.0, 1.764, 8.571, 8.641, num],
['H', 7.745, 6.661, 5.264, 4.243, 2.817, 2.176, 'BOND', 7.754, 6.77, 7.03, 5.444, 5.152, 4.431, 4.767, 3.134, 2.593, 2.522, 3.075, 1.766, 1.764, 0.0, 8.889, 8.799, num],
['H', 1.892, 2.577, 3.705, 4.854, 6.095, 7.318, 8.579, 2.873, 3.319, 2.303, 3.591, 4.29, 5.278, 4.73, 6.029, 6.47, 7.606, 7.235, 9.443, 8.571, 8.889, 0.0, 'BOND', num],
['N', 'BOND', 2.499, 3.559, 4.897, 6.078, 7.404, 8.614, 2.011, 3.175, 2.666, 3.52, 3.889, 5.266, 5.001, 6.057, 6.279, 7.652, 7.472, 9.532, 8.641, 8.799, 'BOND', 0.0, num]]
```

Where `num` is the distance from "start". Obviously in this case `num` in last row should be `0` because nitrogen is defined as "start". And `num` on the second row should be `1` since this carbon is bound to the nitrogen etc.

I tried something like this:

```
def find_distance_from_start(data):
    new_data = data
    count = 0 #count is "num" that should be added to the end of each row of new_data (except the first row, obviously)

    for i, row1 in enumerate(data):
        if data[i][0] == "N" or data[i][0] == "O":
            start_index = i
            new_data[i].append(count)

            atoms_to_check = [index for index, value in enumerate(data[start_index])
                              if value == "BOND" and data[0][index] != "H"] #this should find atoms that are bound to "start" or whatever atom we are looking at

            for atom in atoms_to_check:
                count += 1
                new_data[atom].append(count)
                atoms_to_check = [index for index, value in enumerate(data[atom])
                                  if value == "BOND" and data[0][index] != "H"]
                continue

    return new_data

x = find_distance_from_start(ls)
for y in x:
    print(y)
```

But this code doesn't work. This problem seems hard for me and I just can't figure this out. Could anyone help?

Comment: You should probably turn the data into a graph and use something like Dijkstra algorithm to find distance from source. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-for-dijkstras-shortest-path-algorithm-greedy-algo-7/

Comment: can you take an example, say `output[3]` and explain what should be the value for `num` please?